# android -Eclipse support library included but a jar files is missing in dependencies

Tags: android, android-support-library

I downloaded the latest version of support library in sdk manager , then I add the latest library from sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat and then add this library to my android project .

since then ,I've got this problem :

Compact 7 is the name of support library that  i've added to my eclipse. 
How should I fix this problem ?

[image]

I've cleaned and rebuild the project but it didn't work.

Comment: Check your jar. Also check the version. AppCompatv21 requires API21.
Also ADT will be out of maintenance at the end of this year.Time to switch to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

From this image . it clearly shows that `Compact7.jar` is corrupted. Delete it and download new Compact7.jar and include it in your library.